# knockoutjs: binding to an observable property outside of an array, in a template

Tags: javascript, data-binding, knockout.js

I'm trying to bind part of a template to a property that is on the root of my data model, while building the template off an observable array.

This jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mgxyE/2/  illustrates compactly what I'm trying to accomplish.

the span `<span data-bind='text: message'></span>` is what is failing because I can't figure out how to set up that binding inside a template. Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your viewmodel has global scope, then you can simply do:

```
<span data-bind='text: model.message'></span>
```

In your fiddle, you would want to change the option from `onLoad` to `no wrap (body)` for how the JavaScript is loaded.

Another options is to pass the value in via `templateOptions`.  This would look like:

```
<div data-bind='template: {name :"nodeTemplate", foreach: nodes, templateOptions: { myMessage: message} }'></div>
```

Then, bind to it like (you could call it message, just used `myMessage` to show where the name comes from):

```
<span data-bind='text: $item.myMessage'></span>
```

Finally, if you use [KO 1.3 beta](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2011/08/31/knockout-1-3-0-beta-available/), which I would recommend, then you can simply do:

```
<span data-bind='text: $root.message'></span>
```

Comment: I imagine that the templateOptions route is the most ko-proper way of doing it.

Comment: I think that in 1.3, using `$root` or `$parent` will likely be the most popular choice.

Comment: perfect! using $root for now but template options looks like a great solution for a more complex template. thanks!

Comment: if using 1.3, the $root is the way to go. Otherwise I would recommend using templateOptions.

Answer (score 1):

With Knockout JS 1.3, you can use the parent binding context:

http://jsfiddle.net/Afx6d/